# In PowerPoint viewer how to go to the end of the slide skipping the animations?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Going through some slides takes a long time because of the many animations involved, I want to skip past all of that and see the slide in its final state. Is there any shortcut or way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you change the "view" in `ppt` so you can skip forward/navigate to any slide of any show and "see" or preview each slide. Practice this "navigation" and "view switch" so you can easily scan any upcoming slide that contains animations and embedded videos that might involve audio or delays in loading with older systems.

I'm a PPT user with a corporate technical direction production background. IOW, I ran hundreds of shows behind the screens, so to speak, and have learned a few things to make a seamless slide show really pop.

So I have encountered such problems but there are almost always workarounds in PowerPoint, thankfully. PowerPoint(ppt) has a huge online following with gurus far more equipped than I to help novices and experts alike. Best of luck.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).